# Android - Any way to test Gestures on the Emulator?

Tags: android

Was wondering if there's any way to test Gestures (eg: Fling) on the Emulator.

I saw a project on google code that lets people simulate the accelerometer, but none of Gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar has already been asked here:

[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

I can confirm that it works because I implemented an onFling listener following that example

Answer (score 1):

Any gestures that don't require multi-touch should work fine on the emulator.  So for example Fling is going to work fine on the emulator, where pinch-zoom is not.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking in 2023 here's what I've found:

Hold `crtl` to get the multi tap indicator thingy to pop up. Then press and hold your click and drag the mouse. Depending on how you move, rotation and pinch gestures are available.

My five minutes of playing  with [RNGH](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/) makes me believe that it favors rotation gestures over pinch (like any gesture that started off as a pinch ended up switching over to being a rotation). I did have to do some gesture compositions, so its possible I configured them wrong, but in 2023 multitouch gestures are available on Android Studio emulators

Comment: I had configured it wrong. After reconfiguring it, confirming it worked on a physical device, Im lefting thinking that the crtl click shortcut is exclusively for rotation gestures

Comment: I had pan, pinch, rotation, and tap gestures. The tap gestures worked fine (last priority). Of the remaining 3, only two work if I tried to get them to work exclusively. If I allow them to run simultaneously, the emulator captures all gestures